# Discord.py sending dm to multiple specific members with interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to send dm to a low number of specific users like 3-5 people every 24 hours but not all users on the server so I cannot iterate everyone in the server. I think I can use tasks for the loop but I don't know what to do next what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` function.
For example:

```py
USER_IDS = [123, 1234]  # specify user ID’s here

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def send_messages():
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)  # specify guild_id here
    for member in filter(lambda member_: member_.id in USER_IDS, guild.members):
        await member.send("test message")

send_messages.start()
```

Comment: ```import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="//")
USER_IDS = [userid1,userid2]
@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
 print("{0.user} is online rn".format(Bot))
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def send_messages():
 guild = Bot.get_guild(myguildid)
 print("testt")
 for member in filter(lambda member_: member_.id in USER_IDS, guild.members):
  await member.send("test dm")
@send_messages.before_loop
async def before():
 await Bot.wait_until_ready()```

Comment: did this but it only gives testt on console not sending any dms any ideas? sorry about the formatting I'm pretty new here

Comment: Did you call `send_messages.start()` method?

Comment: yes I called it at the bottom line of the main file I forgot to add it here

Comment: You need to enable `Members Intent` to to it. Enable it on Discord Developers Portal website first. And then add this to your code:
```Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="//", intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Comment: Without this Discord intent your bot can not see any guild members except itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now and I also ticked these intents in discord applications panel thanks